# Don't understand how method "delete" work in linkedlist

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

please help me to understand how does the method delete (with specifying value) work?

I understood everything except this point.

I wrote method delete but don't understand how changing field next in Link "previous" weigh with Link first, I know that the next Link will be missed, but this Link also will be missed in the first List. (it means that I don't understand how to reference type work)

```
package Book.LinkedList;

/**
 * Created by Сергей on 06.07.2015.
 */
public class Link {

    Link(int serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
        next = null;
    }
    private int serial;
    private Link next;



    public void setSerial(int serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
    }
    public int getSerial() {
        return serial;
    }
    public void setNext(Link tmp) {
        next = tmp;
    }
    public Link getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.print(serial + " ");
    }
}

     package Book.LinkedList;


    public class LinkList {
        LinkList() {
            first = null;


        }

        private Link first;

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return first == null;
        }

        public void insertFirst(int serial) {
        Link newLink = new Link(serial);
            if(first == null ) { newLink.setNext(null); }
            else {
                newLink.setNext(first);
            }
           first = newLink;
        }

        public void deleteFirst(){
            if( isEmpty() == false){
                first = first.getNext();
                System.out.println("The link was successfully deleted!");

            }

            else {
                System.out.println("The LinkList is empty, we can't delete element!");
            }

        }
        public boolean find(int key) {
            Link current = first;
            if (current == null) {
                System.out.println("The list is empty.");
                return false;
            }
            do {
                if (current.getSerial() == key) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
            }
            while (current != null);
            return false;
        }
        // delete chosen/ selected element
        // пока не понятно как данное удаление влияет именно на first, почему удаляется из first
        public void delete(int key) {
            Link previous = null;
            Link current = first;
            if (current == null) {
                System.out.println("The list is empty.");
                return;
            }
            do {
                if (current.getSerial() == key) {
                    if(previous == null) { first = first.getNext(); return;}
                    else {
                        previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                        return;
                    }

                }
                else {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
            }
            while (current != null);
            System.out.println("There isn't element with entered serial;");

        }

        public void displayList() {
            Link current  = first;
            while(current != null) {
                current.display();
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            System.out.println("The linkList was successfully displayed");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can imagine it better visually:

[image: Delete linked list]

We make the `next` link skip a step in the chain, and then we simply remove the no longer needed node. Though in this case *we* is a bit misleading, as we never invoke deletion directly. We are just removing all references of the node, so the garbage collector will remove it after a while.

---

#### Pseudocode for this algorithm

1. IF the first element is null, then the list empty, DONE
2. IF the next element is to be removed THEN

   - IF the element to be removed is the first one: `first = first.next()` and **DONE**,
   - ELSE its not he first: just skip the node and **DONE**
3. ELSE GOTO 2.
4. If we got here, there was no matching element

What you need to see, that in both cases where the *done* is highlighted, all references are lost to the node.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I understand what this image means, but don't understand this: current Link it's reference to Link first, previous Link it's reference to current. so when we skip one of the Link( writing to field next of Link previous the next Link of Link current) why does it influence on first?

Comment: which line do you refer to? Unfortunately I did not understand your question.

Comment: look at this method in mentioned code. I understand that "previous" will miss one element if we will find coincidence (current.getSerial() == key) but I don't understand how does it influence on our all linkedList where first element it's "first" . When I display all my linkedList I won't see the deleted element. do you understand me?

Comment: According to your 'We are just removing all references of the node, so the garbage collector will remove it after a while.'. I know it, but in our case we remove reference just from Link previous and all chain with Link first still know about deleted node in chain previous(of course, I understand that my knowledge is wrong,  because I don't understand this point)

Comment: This is not a doubly linked list, we only have forward references.

Comment: Hello meskobalazs,  sorry for delay, I didn't have opportunity to answer. I understood my mistake, I didn't understand how Link first  lose reference to our deleted Node, but know I see. thanks one more time)